# How do I open the ASPNETDB.MDF database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005, aspnetdb

I am using vusiaul studio 2005. I have been unable to use the express database. I can create it, by simply tryign to log in. But if I try to open the ASPNETDB.MDF database itself I get the following error:

"This server version is not supported.  You must have Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Beta 2 or later."

I have SQL 2005 loaded on my machine. I would think this would be enough. Anyone know where I can ge the Beta 2 download or does anyone have another resolution for this?

I am using XP Pro

Answer (score 0):

Checking google, it looks like this is fixed with VS 2005's SP1.

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/28621-Problem-connecting-VS-SQL-Server.aspx